# Typescript: Form an Object from String Array

Tags: typescript

i want to ask is there any way to form a function in typescript that can enable autocomplete when using array.reduce?

ex:

```
function formObject<T>(arr: T[]): ?? {
  return arr.reduce((memo, val) => {
    memo[val] = 'test'
    return memo
  }, {})
}

const array = ["foo", "bar"]
const object = formObject(array);
const testObject2 = formObject(["another"])
```

hoping that i will get autocomplete for object like this

```
const a = object.foo  // type string and foo is autocomplete
const b = object.bar // type string and bar is autocomplete

const c = testObject2.another // type string and another is autocomplete

const d = object.another // return type error because there's no another in object
```

Comment: Did you mean `const object = formObject(array);`

Comment: If array is known at the compile time, this doesn't make much sense, why would you rewrite a known array to an object rather than just create the object. If the array is not known, it doesn't make sense either as you wouldn't be able to write any code using properties not known at compile time. Is there any practical scenario behind this?

Comment: @WiktorZychla One example of where this would be useful is when the type of the array is known at compile-time, a-la an API response of a known shape, but the data itself arrives async in the runtime.

Comment: @WiktorZychla yes, to answer you, this just some curiosity on how to get value from array and position that string into some object, because all i get from tutorial is that using object type instead of array. 
```[K in keyof O]``` 
or 
```[K in O]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible. The question is if you really need this...

We can create a generic type `StringArrToObject` which takes a tuple `T` and creates an object with every element of `T` as a key.

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

type StringArrToObject<T extends string[]> = Expand<{
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string ? T[K] : never]: string
}>
```

Don't mind the `Expand` type here. This is just there to make the type prettier.

We can now use this in the function `formObject`.

```
function formObject<
  T extends string[]
>(arr: readonly [...T]): StringArrToObject<T> {
  return arr.reduce((memo, val) => {
    memo[val] = 'test'
    return memo
  }, {} as Record<string, any>) as any
}
```

Let's see this function in action:

```
const array = ["foo", "bar"] as const
const obj = formObject(array);
// const obj: {
//     foo: string;
//     bar: string;
// }


const testObject2 = formObject(["another"])
// const testObject2: {
//     another: string;
// }
```

Important detail here: See how we have to use `as const` for the `array` variable. Otherwise the type information about specific elements will be lost.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4&ssl=26&ssc=5&pln=15&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAogDwgQwHYBMA8AVAfDAXhmxigRCgwGcYBLVAMygCcYB5GAfhgG8YBtANJ1UMANZQwAewbsAugC52QuTAC%20MJaigA3FgG5goSLADKIZvQDmAQWbNsUtgCMAVlADGIHKXKV0NFQW1vxy%20ESIKBiYPMAwAsL04pIyxDDINNgqvhTUMEGWqFZcxNlauiyK%20cFFwGq4RgwArqhetFKiDFLMALYu7l4%20ZLkB1YVWobgAFMj2SsxQyOgdADZgAgB0W9hyAJRK5uN2Dk5unt54vHEwCyBNzKKzzBsL6E0eUFNTPVA9UgA0MB0yBWu0I%20Fi8XiPz%20-GBK1URAA5BQgkjrvFbvdRDCpNc1ICeBoMjAAEqebpYArWQFoMC4MEkul1IweDpBdL2ZDrIj8ABEXSkfMBfOcsz5qhJbNQQWA0o5UjchBgXV6-XOMy5YF2hgA9LqYPKQDBFa4lLF9VD4oKlNSinqDVaxcxbTUrA71EY5ezjaiQOqvAAmZWqvpnLxTfloKQgAAWLAlu2AlqNMD9AZAgfNycdUOjcZYrvGHrUwCAA)

---

But keep in mind: This type implementation only works for this specific `array.reduce()` implementation. If you change the logic inside the function, you will also have to change the type to reflect the changed behaviour. So this is not a generic type that would work for any `reduce` implementation.

Comment: This really answer my question but there's some syntax that i rarely see so i'll ask in here

in the code 
```function formObject<
  T extends string[]
>(arr: readonly [...T]): StringArrToObject<T> {
}```
in there you using 
```arr: readonly [...T]```
instead what i understand is T is some string[], what's the use of spread it like that?

Comment: I prepared [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnaJew) which describes the concepts